# Android Sqlite result start with zero

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

Morning

Hopefully this will be a generically simple question for someone

I currently have a database within my Android studio project of which it contains times e.g. the hours in a 24 clock standard.

When searching for an hour which starts with a zero e.g. 09 I simply get the result 0 but If I search for 13 I will then receive the correct result of 13.

I Just wanted to know if there is a way of searching for results which start with a zero?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you store times in db like 9:52 with no leading zero when needed.  
You must store the times in db in the format `hh:mm`.